# How to compare HTML markup in Golang?

Tags: html, go, canonicalization

I'm trying to come up with a test suite which checks HTML fragments/files are canonically equivalent to one another. I was surprised to see that if I parse the same string or file, the https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Node was comparing as different. What am I missing?

Hopefully this demonstrates the issue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    s := `<h1>
    test
    </h1><p>foo</p>`
    // s2 := `<h1>test</h1><p>foo</p>`

    doc, _ := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    doc2, _ := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))

    if doc == doc2 {
        fmt.Println("HTML is the same") // Expected this
    } else {
        fmt.Println("HTML is not the same") // Got this
    }
}
```

**HTML is not the same**

Comment: check what html.Parse is actually returning.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to walk it... http://s.natalian.org/2016-05-28/compare2.go or what do you mean?

Comment: in compare2.go: in the final iteration, c is nil, so it gets to Downhere, but it does not seem the same issue as the question where doc and doc2 hold addresses which are not the same.

Comment: `reflect.DeepEqual` might work

Comment: Hoping something might come through here: https://github.com/xi2/htmlnode/issues/1#issuecomment-222336736

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use reflection, since `html.Parse` returns `*Node` object. Comparing two of objects in Go need a `reflect.DeepEqual`.

```
if reflect.DeepEqual(doc, doc2) {                                     
        fmt.Println("HTML is the same") 
} else {
        fmt.Println("HTML is not the same")                         
}
```

This prints out "HTML is the same".

Comment: Is there is a space, it says it's not the same. :/ http://s.natalian.org/2016-05-29/so.go

Comment: I ended up doing a simpler strings.Contains based test https://github.com/kaihendry/toc/blob/master/toc_test.go